# Why total memory goes high when taking a snapshot from JetBrains dotMemory

Tags: java, c, garbage-collection, jetbrains-ide, dotmemory

I just trying to take a snapshot from JetBrains dotMemory application and, I noticed that when we are taking a snapshot, looks like the total memory is increasing little bit. So could someone know the reason for this?

before taking the snapshot:
[image]

After taking the snapshot:
[image]

If you guys can look at these two images, there are considerable memory changes with Unmanaged memory.

Comment: Why the `C` tag?

Comment: You are using a profiler for .NET to analyze a Java application?

Answer (score 0):

In order to profile application Windows Profiling API injects a native dll (part of dotMemory written in C++) into the address space of the profilee application. To collect and write a graph of objects (memory snapshot) to the disk the code in this dll also allocates some memory, it leads increasing of usage of **native** memory. Note, that usage of .NET (managed) memory of your application didn't increase.